# How to detect pinch to zoom in Google Maps v2

Tags: android, kotlin, zooming, google-maps-api-2, pinchzoom

I have project where I have used Google Maps v2 and, in there there are some auto zoom functions which are working quite well.

But now the users complaints and wants the auto zoom functions to turn off when they touch the screen in a zoom pinch (either outwards (zooming in) or inwards (zooming out)). Is there a good way to detect that particular zoom event without disrupting the manual zooming, so I can turn off my autozoom.

Using google maps v2 in android kotlin.

I.E.

```
...

override fun onViewCreated(view:View,savedInstanceState:Bundle?){
  ...
  val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?

  ...

  mapFragment?.getMapAsync{_googleMap->
    _googleMap?.let{safeGoogleMap->
      googleMap = safeGoogleMap
    }?:let{
      Log.e(TAG,"Map couldn`t be created")
      Message.error("Map couldn`t be created")
      return@getMapAsync
    }

    //How to detect two finger zoom in or out pinch here



    //   

  }

}
```

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?